# How to check if a relation exists with MongoID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have 'users' and 'favorites', in a many-to-many relationship.

To add a favorite to a user, I could do something like this:

```
user.favorites << my_new_favorite unless user.favorites.include?(my_new_favorite)
```

The problem is that this is not how I would do it in Mongo. This is fetching all the user's favorites (could be thousands), only to check if one of them exists.

Any ideas on how to optimize that line of code to be more performant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own link() function, based on @rubish answer.

Add this to initializers/mongoid.rb:

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def link(entity)
      add_to_set((entity.class.name.demodulize.downcase!.to_s + '_ids').to_sym, entity.id)
      save!() unless persisted?
      entity.add_to_set((self.class.name.demodulize.downcase!.to_s + '_ids').to_sym, id)
    end
  end
end
```

And then just link() your many-to-many related entities, eg:

```
my_new_favorite = Favorite.find_or_initialize_by(:field => 'value')
user.link(my_new_favorite)
```

Improvements are welcome, I started using ruby last month.

Comment: That's basically how mongoid's has_and_belongs_to_many function works. http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoid's [add_to_set](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#add_to_set) method here.

```
user.add_to_set(:favorite_ids, my_new_favorite.id)
```

Comment: So I will have to do 2 add_to_set calls. I can't believe mongoId does not contemplate such basic scenario. This should solve the performance issue though, I will probably accept this answer.

Comment: It'd not a mongoid issue - it's fundamental to how document stores work. Mongoid does provide a habtm option that handles this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think the check is necessary at all - Mongoid will automatically handle removing dupes from associations, so just append the favorite as you normally would.

Comment: Actually user.favorites is just a regular array. When calling user.save!, MongoID will only check that there are no duplicates in favorite.users, but will add a new entry to user.favorites. Not sure if this is by design or a bug.